# How to export multiple objects from a .vue file

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, es6-modules

I'm using `typescript` with Vue. And for this specific use case, I'd like to export multiple items from my `.vue` file. Like this:

// FooBar.vue

```
<template>
    ...
</template>

export class Foo extends Vue {
    foo: string = "foo";
}

export const Bar = {bar: "bar"};
```

And then import them like this:

// Baz.vue

```
import { Foo, Bar } from 'FooBar.vue';

@Components({ components: { Foo }})
... // rest of the code
```

**Is there a way to export multiple objects from a `.vue` file in Vue?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your vue file write:

```
class Foo extends Vue {
    foo: string = "foo";
}

const Bar = { bar: "bar" };

export { Bar };
export default Foo;
```

You will then be able to import these using:

```
import Foo, { Bar } from 'FooBar.vue';
```

More detailed information on how export works can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

Comment: I found one gotcha: `Foo` has to be the **default export**, otherwise the other components won't see it.

Comment: For me this doesn't seem to work. The compiler complains about not being able to find `Bar`.

Comment: I get as well a warning Module "*.vue" has no exported... for the non default export ( in my case an interface). It somehow works halfway... Code compiles and runs but the typescript code does not recognize the interface. (type stays any). i just keep all other declarations i want now in a separate ts file.